# Are Powerpoint 2013 slides wider than Powerpoint 2010 ones?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am switching from Powerpoint 2010 to 2013. I just noticed that the blank slides created in PPT 2013 seems to be wider than older slides created with PPT 2010. For example, I took a screenshot, which show the new slides created with 2013 above, and 2010 below. The heights seem to be the same by visual inspection.

[image]

Is this an known behavior? And are there options to make the 2013 slides backward compatible with prior versions?

Comment: By default yes as the are optimized for wide screen. You can change the sizes, even to a custom size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default slide size for Power Point 2010 is 4:3 (Standard), whereas the default slide size for Power Point 2013 is 16:9 (Widescreen).

You can change it from:

**Design → Slide Size → Standard (4:3)**

You can do the same on Power Point 2010 to change the slide size to 16:9.

Comment: However, from 2103 on, choosing 16:9/widescreen gives you slide that are 7.5" high by 13.333" wide (or the equivalent in cm if you live in a place with a sensible measurement system).  In 2010, 16:9/Widescreen gives you 5.63" x 10" slides. For the sake of compatibility moving forward, you're far better off choosing Custom in PPT 2010 and specifiying 13.333 w by 7.5 h.